# WPF Height at Runtime

Tags: wpf, runtime, height

I am new to WPF. A Problem I am trying to solve is how I can get a correct height at runtime.

In my Application I dynamically add Usercontrols to a Stackpanel in the Code behind. The Usercontrol contains a few Texblocks. My Stackpanel is then used as Content for a BookPage and this BookPage is added to a Book(http://wpfbookcontrol.codeplex.com/). The Height of my Stackpanel should not exceed a certain value.

I already figured out that I can use Measure & Arrange to calculate the ActualSize & Height of the Usercontrol:

```
itemsa.Measure(new System.Windows.Size(double.PositiveInfinity,     double.PositiveInfinity));
itemsa.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, 400, itemsa.DesiredSize.Height));
```

At this point the Usercontrol isn't added to the Stackpanel. 400 is the Width my usercontrol shouldn't exceed, but it does, because the Textblock dosn't create automatic linebreaks. When I display the Book the linebreaks are created.

What should I do to solve this Problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a question: Measure and Arrange? All UserControls have a property named `RenderSize`, keeping the rendered parameters (`RenderSize.Width` and `RenderSize.Height`), or you could use the properties `ActualHeight` and `ActualWidth` as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you're looking for this, but with the [MaxHeight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.maxheight.aspx) property you have the possibility to restrict the growing of a control.

In general, it's not necessary to override Measure and Arrange, the Layout-System is very powerfull and it offers you many [container-controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms745058.aspx) that provide specific layout behaviour.

Comment: I need to make this calculations, because i have to start adding the controls to a new Stackpanel after the first one is "full".

Comment: @TheJoelaut: Maybe the WrapPanel will help you? If this not us usefull, try to give the limitations to your Measure()-Call. Measure is responsible to do the calculations (first pass of the layout system).

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the property MaxHeight for the stackpanel?

Also ActualWidth and ActualHeight will tell you the actual size of a control.

Are you sure you need all these calculations? My guess is that it would be better to use auto sizing GridRows or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you want a custom panel to do layout in a very specific manner.  You can inherit a new class from Panel, and then override MeasureOverride and ArrangeOverride to determine what can be added and where.  This is also the method you'd use to do a virtual panel, where only the visible children are created and they are destroyed when scrolled off.

If you are interested in this let me know and I'll edit the post and provide an example.